# How to make a previously existing project/application responsive in angular 6

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have an application in angular 6 in which i have also used Modal.
I want to make this application responsive.
How i can proceed for that?
Do i need to change html code for each and every control on component?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [Ng-Bootstrap library](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) available which could be used to power up the Ng App to make it responsive. This library also supports modals.
Moreover, you also have to update some HTML to add classes and there might be some additional js to include as well(depending upon your app.)